# jQuery select box interaction

Tags: jquery, html, select, drop-down-menu

I have got a working jsFiddle of a select drop-down box but it's not quite the result I need. For this example I have used 'Port of Auckland'. If you click 'Port of Auckland' it will show it's content but I would like the drop-box value to change so it matches the port you're viewing.

**UPDATE** Solution was to use the prop function. Also, instead of duplicating all the ports... is there any easier way to minify the jQuery to work for all? I then won't have to show/hide heaps of elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/an173g55/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="all"){
                $(".auckland").hide();
                $(".all").show();   
            }
           if($(this).attr("value")=="auckland"){
                $(".all").hide();
                $(".auckland").show();

            }
        });
    }).change();

    $('.auckland-link').click(function() {
    $('.auckland').show();
    $(".all").hide();
});


});
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it using jQuery .prop() method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="all"){
                $(".auckland").hide();
                $(".all").show();



            }
           if($(this).attr("value")=="auckland"){
                $(".all").hide();
                $(".auckland").show();

            }
        });
    }).change();

    $('.auckland-link').click(function() {
        $('select option:contains("Auckland")').prop('selected', true);
        $('.auckland').show();
        $(".all").hide();
});


});
```

Here is a working sample of it, forked from your Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lny58ve3/2/

Comment: Thanks for reply. That works nicely. Is there any easier way to work this jQuery without duplicating all the ports? At the moment this is just 1 port but I have to do it to the rest.

Comment: @user1628845 if the option name in the select is the same as your title, you could use:
$('select option:contains("'+$(this).html()+'")').prop('selected', true);